# 2012 quo. no. 14 $F_{net} = ma$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

Please refer to #14 in [this document](http://www.aapt.org/physicsteam/2013/upload/exam1-2012-unlocked.pdf)

Please help me solve this problem... I don't understand why a force (in the problem, T) even needs to be applied to keep the ball in equilibrium. There is no rolling motion, because static friction is not even acting on the ball yet (since friction is a lazy force).

Thanks for your time!

PS: I'm not really sure what to classify this problem as, so perhaps someone could fix the tags, or suggest some.

Comment: Yeah, we need to know what _your_ question is, not what a teacher or a book asks of for _you_ to do.

Comment: Don't you think that hole drilled *asymmetrically* through the cylinder would, shall we say, 'want to be' oriented differently?

Comment: @AlfredCentauri is there a formula I can use to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a force T because the system is no longer in equilibrium. It is not because of the friction, but because of gravity. Now that the two halves of the cylinder do not weight the same, there will be a net torque thet would make the object to rotate counterclockwise. Even in absense of friction the problem would remain the same, the only dffference should be that, in order to avoid a translation in absende of friction, you should apply the force vertically. So you need a tension so that  the torque will remain zero. I leave the homework to you.

The weight of the amount taken from the hole is 15N, because it started at 80N and ended at 65N. So, the is now an excess weight of 15N, at e adistance of $2a/5$ on the side of the cylinder that was not drilled. To be in equilibriums the total torque mus be zero. Using the center of the cilinder as the origin of coordinates, we can equal the torque made by the force, T, and the torque by the gravity. You get:

aT=2/5 a 15N

after simplifying you get T=6N

Comment: Is not homework ._., but how would I find the torque..